# character or pattern recognition

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm trying to make a character recognition using linear network but I'm getting some error when running my code, anyone who can help me with a single or basic explanation or how I can go about it? below is my code

```
A1 = [ 0 0 1 1 0 0 0;
       0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
       0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
       0 0 1 0 1 0 0;
       0 0 1 0 1 0 0;
       0 1 1 1 1 1 0;
       0 1 0 0 0 1 0;
       0 1 0 0 0 1 0;
       1 1 1 0 1 1 1];
B1 = [ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
       1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
       1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
C1 = [ 0 0 1 1 1 1 1;
       0 1 0 0 0 0 1;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
       0 1 0 0 0 0 1;
       0 0 1 1 1 1 0];
A2 = [ 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
       0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
       0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
       0 0 1 0 1 0 0;
       0 0 1 0 1 0 0;
       0 1 0 0 0 1 0;
       0 1 1 1 1 1 0;
       0 1 0 0 0 1 0;
       0 1 0 0 0 1 0];
B2 = [ 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
       1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
       1 1 1 1 1 1 0];
C2 = [ 0 0 1 1 1 0 0;
       0 1 0 0 0 1 0;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
       1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
       0 1 0 0 0 1 0;
       0 0 1 1 1 0 0];

p = [A1(1:end); B1(1:end); C1(1:end)]';
t = [A2(1:end); B2(1:end); C2(1:end)]';

net = newlin(minmax(p),1);
net.trainParam.goal = 10e-5;
net.trainParam.epochs = 500;
net = train(net, p, t);
```

my error is on line 62 and the code on line 62 is

```
net = train(net, p, t);
```

anyone with a good example or how i can make this code run?thanks in advance im trying to learn and im new to matlab

Comment: **What** error do you get? If you genuinely want to learn, learn about the Matlab debugging tools: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html

Comment: @nkjt its just saying error on line 62 net = train(net, p, t);

Comment: That sounds very unlikely, normally it would trace back to what line in `train` it errored at, and then there would be some sort of explanation (e.g. 'Inputs and input states have different numbers of samples.')  If you genuinely only get one error line there is something very odd going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the code and the error states: Output data size does not match net.outputs{1}.size.
Check the format for matrix sizes. I think that is the issue.